# How to open files in vertically/horizontal split windows in Vim from the command line

Tags: vim, command-line, window

There must be a way, something like this:

```
vim -[option] <file-list>
```

to open files *from command prompt* and *not* from within Vim.

- split windows vertically or/and horizontally
- in separate tabs

Answer (score 487, accepted):

From `vim --help`:

```
-p[N]  Open N tab pages (default: one for each file)
-o[N]  Open N windows (default: one for each file)
-O[N]  Like -o but split vertically
```

So type this to open files split horizontally, for example:

```
vim -o file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
```

If `N` is provided the `N` windows/tabs will be opened. If `N` is less than the number of files in arguments, then the remaining files will be loaded in hidden buffers. If `N` is greater than the number of arguments, the remaining windows/tabs will be editing an empty file.

Comment: Really? I've never had to provide an N.

Comment: Indeed, it seems to be something in my .vimrc causing the trouble. If I move it aside, -o without N works as documented.

Comment: `-o` is like `:split`, `-O` is like `:vsplit`

Comment: @user3338098 I *think* there may have been a deleted comment here; Laurence's "Indeed..." comment implies that it was causing problems when omitted.

Answer (score 509):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd> (case does not matter) for horizontal splitting

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>v</kbd> (lower case) for vertical splitting

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>q</kbd> (lower case) to close one

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to switch between windows

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>,  <kbd>j</kbd> (or <kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>h</kbd>, <kbd>l</kbd>; lowercase) to switch to adjacent window (down, up, left, right respectively)

Comment: To switch screens, Press `Ctrl-w` and then `up arrow` or `down arrow` to switch screens.

Comment: Ah but you can use regular vim movements, e.g. `ctrl+w j` to jump to the buffer below the current one.

Comment: swapped order of down and up for `Ctrl + W` `J`(down) and `Ctrl + W` `K`(up)

Comment: Thanks this helped me figure out how to move backwards, `Ctrl + w` `left arrow`.  I always use `ctrl + ww` to cycle forward.  If your on the bottom and need to access a file on the top quickly, and don't want to go forward, you need to move up first with `ctrl + w` `up arrow` before moving left(or right).  Thanks.

Comment: @Atav32 I was responding to a comment, not a question, and this is Superuser, not stack overflow. The comment used the wrong term and I asked a simple question in response in an attempt to politely point this out as you can't moderate comments and it's not wrong enough to warrant a flag.  Plus it didn't work anyway, no matter what you call it.

Comment: +1 for ctrl-w v. I was gettting really good at typing :vert

Comment: @Lucas: Too slow :P

Comment: For left right split, `Ctrl+W` then `W`, or `Ctrl+W` then `Left/Right Arrow` works.

Answer (score 398):

While running vim:

1. `:sp filename` for a horizontal split
2. `:vsp filename` or `:vs filename` for a vertical split

Comment: This doesn't answer the question raised...but it SURE helped me out :D  Thanks!

Comment: thanks, just what I was looking for. I also `:set splitright`

Comment: ctrl-ww for switching between splits

Comment: `:vsplit filename` is the same as `:vsp filename` and `:vs filename`, but perhaps a tiny bit easier to remember for some people

Answer (score 23):

another interested trick is the CLI -p argument - which opens them in separate **tabs** for recent versions of vim and gvim.

```
gvim -p file1.txt file2.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Another useful trick that I just found out, is that you can use wildcards in the filelist to open multiple files. Say you want to open file1.txt, file2.txt, and file3.txt all in separate tabs but don't feel like typing that all out you can just do:

`vim -p file*`

I frequently find myself needing to open a lot of files with a similar prefix, and this has been quite helpful

Comment: That does not have to do with Vim itself but with the shell you are using. It is the shell that expands globs.