# VIM Vex select file to current split

Tags: vim

When you use

```
:Vex /dir
```

It shows all the files. How do I open the file in the vertical split thats open for me?

The answers [here](https://superuser.com/questions/486532/how-to-open-files-in-vertically-horizontal-split-windows-in-vim-from-the-command) all assume vim is closed or demonstrate how to open the split view not the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press `<CR>`.

See `:help netrw-quickmaps`.

By the way, neither the question you linked to nor the answers have anything to do with your issue.